# disabling imagebutton inside itemtemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i disable/hide a button inside that is inside a itemtemplate? i want to hide the save button on load, and then show it and hide the edit button when the edit button is clicked.

The template:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="loginstyling/images/Edit.png" Visible="true" />
   <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="loginstyling/images/Save.png" Visible="true" OnClick="ImageButtonUpdate_Click" />
   <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="loginstyling/images/Remove.png"/>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Behind:

```
        private void ImageButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButtonUpdate.Enabled = false; // not working, dosnt find the button
    }
```

Comment: what version of asp.net are you using?
also make sure you are clear about the differences between enable and visible

Answer (score 1):

use the `sender` of the event

```
protected void ImageButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ImageButton btnupdate= sender as ImageButton;
    btnupdate.Enabled = false;
    //if you need to get other controls in the same row
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btnupdate.NamingContainer;
    var btnedit=  (ImageButton)row.FindControl("ImageButtonEdit");
    btnedit.Enabled = false; // do enable or disable as you need
}
```

Comment: but how do i in the same buttonclick update the ImageButtonEdit then?

Answer (score 1):

You Need to retrieve the ImageButton as follows as it is residing in the GridView

```
private void ImageButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Get the ImageButton that raised the event
     ImageButton btn = (ImageButton )sender;
     btn .Enabled = false; 
}
```

**Edit**

*Step 1*

Provide same Onclick event for `Update` and `Edit` i.e

```
OnClick="ImageButtonUpdate_Click"
```

*Step 2*

Use `CommandName` Attribute

```
     ImageButton btn = (ImageButton )sender;
      if(btn.CommandName =="Update")
       {
            btn.Enabled = false;
       }
      if(btn.CommandName =="Edit")
        {
          btn.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: but how do i in the same buttonclick update the ImageButtonEdit then?

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft your `btn` will have attribute `commandname` with that you can update the `imagebuttonedit`

Comment: Mind giving me an example? ive no idea how i would do this.

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft did you tried my update? or is this what you expecting?

Comment: sorry for the late answer, something came up. sorry for this question but i get the 'checkin_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ImageButtonUpdate_Click'  how come when i have it listed in the aspx and the cs. do you know?